# Intel Advisor - view results from Linux cloud on local Windows GUI

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, profiling, intel-advisor

With Intel Advisor, I ran the following on Linux in the cloud and downloaded the result folders to my local WIndows machine:

```
advixe-cl --collect=survey ./My_Program.exe
advixe-cl --collect=map ./My_Program .exe
advixe-cl --collect=dependencies ./My_Program .exe
```

Then I opened my Windows GUI for Advisor. I clicked the "Open Result" icon and opened the advixeproj file. It correctly shows sub-folders for survey, map and dependencies. When I open any of them, all I see in each of the window panes is:

```
 No Data
 To collect data about your application's performance, compile your application in Release Build settings and run Survey analysis.
```

My application is a C program (My_Program.exe) that calls a shared object written in assembly language (NASM). I assume Advisor can work with assembly language programs and shared objects because VTune does, so I don't think that's the problem.

Next to the Application field I click "Browse" and browse to the My_Program.exe, but Advisor says the file "is not an executable binary." Maybe that's because this is Windows and the binary is for Linux.

My question is: how do I view results from a Linux cloud server downloaded to my local Windows machine for analysis with the Windows GUI?   I do that regularly with VTune without any problems.

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably much better to ask this kind of question on the dedicated [Intel's forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Development-Tools/ct-p/software-dev-tools).

Comment: Here is the link to the advisor forum on intel.com: https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers-Intel-VTune-Profiler/bd-p/analyzers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - the method described in the question is generally correct, but for Advisor it is also important to specify *--project-dir* (keep it the same accross all analysis types).

```
1) [on linux] advixe-cl --collect=survey  --project-dir ./my_project_dir  ./My_Program.exe

2) [on linux] advixe-cl --collect=tripcounts  --project-dir ./my_project_dir  ./My_Program.exe
```

etc..

```
3) copy my_project_dir folder from Linux to Windows

4) [on windows in Advisor GUI or with advixe-gui - open] ./my_project_dir and use "Show My Result" button.
```

This is covered on Intel forum  too, as noted in "comments" to the original question.

In addition There are 2 other different methods : using --snapshot command or just exchaning interactive HTML GUIs (available for Roofline and Offload features). They are described at e.g. given nice article: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/advisor-cookbook/top/analyze-performance-remotely-and-visualize-results-on-macos.html

Comment: Also see https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers-Intel-VTune-Profiler/Use-Intel-Advisor-on-Linux-cloud-and-analyze-locally-on-Windows/m-p/1187117#M18945.